# R: How to crop and mask a list of raster by a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, mask, raster

I want to crop and mask a list of rasters by a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. The spdf is a country from the GADM, here an example with Iran how I would do it only for one raster:

```
library(raster)

iran <- getData("GADM", country = "IRN", level = 1)
r <- raster(iran, nrow=100, ncol=100)
set.seed(-99)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r2 <- crop(r, iran)
res <- mask(r2, iran)
```

However, I have a lot of rasters (66 raster for 4 different countries) and I don't want to copy paste my code. Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: do you have a different spdf for each country?

Comment: I have four different spdfs, but all four will be run on all 66 rasters

Comment: You can create a raster brick, and then crop and mask the raster brick by your spdf's.

Comment: thanks for the idea, my problem was that I first read the one layer raster using brick() instead of raster(). Therefore I get an error trying to brick multiple already bricked raster. The cropping and masking works now

Comment: So your first raster is in its own rasterBrick, and the other 65 are in another rasterBrick?